# Could not retrive data with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a problem with the axios libary.

The data which I would like to retrive have the following structure:

```js
data= [
    {'id': 1 'name': 'me'}, 
    {'id': 2 'name': 'you'}
]
```

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
        
useEffect( () => {
   axios.get(https://myurl.com)
        .then(res => setItems(...items, {res.data} ))
        
}, [items]);
```

The error is arund this area {res.data}. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting and what is your expecting?

Answer (score 0):

This line has a few syntax issues:

```js
.then(res => setItems(...items, {res.data} ))
```

1. If you are spreading `items` you need to spread it *into* something, in this case a new array.
2. It looks like you are trying to create a new object with `{res.data}` but `res.data` is already an object ([given axios' `get()` API](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)).

Assuming `data` from the response is an array, you can do the following:

```js
.then(res => setItems([...items, ...res.data]));
```

Or you can destructure `data` from `res`:

```js
.then(({ data }) => setItems([...items, ...data]));
```

Comment: Can you explain, why this is the solution?